# Does ZFS make sense as local storage?

Tags: storage, zfs

I was reading about ZFS and for a moment thought of using it in my computer, but than reading about its memory requirements I thought twice.

Does it make sense to use ZFS as local storage or this makes mroe sense for servers used as storage? (Even for servers with other uses it seems an overkill).

Comment: In some cases it makes excellent sense, it some it does not. Overall the answers you might get will vary a lot and many of those will be opinion based.  If you want proper answers then use the [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/979682/edit) link to make the question significantly more detailed and focussed on a practical thing to which we can provide practical answers.

Comment: As for memory requirements, those vary a lot with selected features. E.g. enabling de-dup increases memory use a lot. If you do not need that then you need less memory. But as written we can only guess.

Comment: @Hennes thanks Would a question like In which circunstances does ZFS make sense as local storage fit?

Comment: First think of what you are trying to do. Do you just want to store files? Do you want to store files and keep the system up ifa disk fails (In which case RAID becomes interesting, both regular of ZFS variants). Do you want checksums on files? Do you want to be able to do very complex things (ZFS is soooo much more than a mere filesystem), or do you want to keep things simple (in which case: ZFS might be unwise).....  Then edit the post.

Comment: @hennes What I really want for now is to explore ZFS. A good way is to install it before using it somehwere else. When I started reading about it, more and more I got the idea that it would be an overkill in terms of memory. I dont have an exact plan. In the future I am mostly interested in a RAID/deduplication and performance (which might sound an ackward mix)

Answer (score -1):

ZFS does not have particularly high memory requirements.

As pointed out in the comments, *certain features* of ZFS (particularly deduplication, but also L2ARC) require a certain amount of memory to be useful.

However, these features are not ones you are likely to use unless you have a particular use-case that implies using them.

[ZFS with its first-layer ARC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS#ZFS_cache:_ARC_.28L1.29.2C_L2ARC.2C_ZIL) (Adaptive Replacement Cache) is not significantly more memory-hungry than any other file system and cache. Because of using [ARC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_replacement_cache) instead of for example a [Least Recently Used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_algorithms) cache algorithm, in some workloads it is able to make more efficient use of the available cache RAM.

**What ZFS *does* require** is ECC RAM. This is ubiquitous on servers, but rarely found on personal systems (many lower-end Intel CPUs don't even support ECC RAM). This requirement stems from ZFS' self-healing properties, because [RAM problems can potentially destroy your data](https://forums.freenas.org/index.php?threads/ecc-vs-non-ecc-ram-and-zfs.15449/) when running ZFS. There is no code to check for this in ZFS, probably in part because [there appears to be no 100% certain way to tell from software](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/139319/2465) whether the system uses ECC RAM.

Whether ZFS makes sense depends on what you are trying to do, the same way as whether NTFS makes sense also depends on what you are trying to do. ZFS does however offer several features that few or no other file systems offer, and which can be highly useful in certain scenarios. *Some* of these are:

- Guaranteed end-to-end data integrity. You will know for certain that if a particular read succeeds, it returned the same data that was originally written to that location. This means that there is no such thing as silent data corruption; you either get your data back, or you get an I/O error.
- File-system-aware striping and redundancy. Normal RAID controllers treat the entire storage device as just a big bunch of blocks, with no knowledge of any on-disk data structures at all. Because ZFS combines the volume management and file system, it is able to make more intelligent decisions in the face of errors. It also has a "most important first" resilver regimen, which means that data that is critical for the functioning of the file system is resilvered first after a failure, and less critical data gets to wait, regardless of where on the disk the data is stored.
- Tiered caching. For example, you can have a RAM ARC, supplemented by a fast SSD L2ARC, with the bulk of data storage on rotational HDDs. For workloads where the working data set can be estimated to a reasonable degree of accuracy, this can provide huge I/O performance improvements at a relatively low cost and certainly without needing to go all SSD.
- Practically free file systems. With ZFS, creating a "file system" is little different from creating a directory in most contemporary file systems. File systems can have different quotas, both maximum and guaranteed. For this reason, with ZFS, file systems are often recommended to be used as administrative boundaries; for example, on a large server, each user's home directory could be its own file system. This isolates portions of the directory tree from each other without the overhead implied by creating separate regular partitions and file systems. I use file systems to separate, for example, my email archives per year, or photographs per month.
- Practically free snapshots. I don't know how many times the fact that I have been able to just go back to how a file looked a few hours before has saved me from some embarassing mistake. Backups provide similar ability (and are still needed, because [no amount of RAID is a backup](https://serverfault.com/q/2888/58408)), but snapshots are much more readily available. In ZFS, a snapshot itself requires only a few kilobytes of metadata storage, regardless of the amount of data in the relevant file system, and comes at no significant performance cost.

*None of these are required to be used just because you use ZFS.* But they are there, generally just a single command away should you wish to enable them.

Now, are these "overkill"? **That really depends a lot on what you are trying to do.** I run ZFS (with ECC RAM) on my home system. For the most part, it has been quietly ticking along, not making any more noise than any other file system would have (and probably less), but it has actually saved me from data corruption at least once (a scrub found a handful of sectors that were showing problems, and *automatically and silently repaired the data* with no intervention required from me). Personally, I figure that **I saved that data for a reason,** and that reason is most likely that I want to refer to the data later. Consider now that [the universe hates your data](http://www.zdnet.com/article/the-universe-hates-your-data/).

With the ever-increasing storage sizes and essentially ever-constant bit error rates (per media class), I/O errors are not going to become less common. Looking at my preferred reseller, both Seagate and HGST offer 8 TB HDDs at prices that are high but not extreme, and certainly within the reach of individuals. That's about 6.4×10^13 bits. With a 10^-14 bit error rate, *even a single full media read pass* is *statistically highly likely* to encounter an I/O problem rendering a whole (4 KiB) sector unreadable. (By the time we hit 10 TB HDDs, statistically *a single full-disk read will encounter at least one unreadable sector*.) There have been studies showing that *undetected* read errors happen a lot more often than we want to admit, despire HDD manufacturers' effort in improving the on-disk ECC algorithms, though I don't have a link readily available. Contemporary file systems like NTFS, ext4, UFS+, HFS+ and so on just aren't prepared to handle such a situation.

That's the niche file systems like ZFS and Btrfs aim to fill.

Comment: ZFS **absolutely does not** require ECC RAM.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq Well, yes and no. It doesn't require ECC RAM in the sense that RAM must be ECC for the ZFS code to run. (Or at least I don't think so. ZoL certainly doesn't.) It does require ECC RAM in the sense that any memory problems are *potentially* more devastating; consider the in-RAM write cache and what happens if there are bit flips between checksum calculation and disk writes. That said, [the discussion starting here](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=1235679&p=26303271#p26303271) seems relevant, and has people arguing both for and against the "ECC RAM is required" stance.

Comment: That I can agree with. There is no requirement for ECC RAM to be able to use ZFS or run the code. Whether or not ECC is required for reliability is a debate that will most likely continue as long as the vi vs. emacs debate. To me the fact that many developers and early advocates of ZFS used it on their laptops makes it pretty clear. The often repeated "because it uses checksums" argument has been completely debunked by both Microsoft and Linux introducing native filesystems that also use checksums with no recommendations for ECC.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq Microsoft has anything native similar? I know it's unrelated to the question, but what file system is that?

Comment: ReFS : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReFS Although first released on Server 2012 it's available on Windows 8.1 desktop and above.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq Interesting. I was not aware of that. Thank you.

Comment: General rule of thumb for ZFS is for each terabyte ZFS needs a gigabyte of RAM which doesn't not include 4 GB generally needed need by ZFS

Comment: @MichaelN Most people don't have sufficiently large storage and sufficiently little memory for that to be a significant problem. And of course, that rule of thumb is for best results; you certainly *can* run ZFS with less, if you are willing to take a bit of a performance hit. (Same as that you can run deduplication with less than 5 GB RAM per 1 TB storage, but you probably don't want to use deduplication at all.) By your own numbers, for 4 TB of raw storage (not unreasonable) you'd need 8 GB of RAM for ZFS (for best performance), or for 8 TB of raw storage you'd need 12 GB of RAM for ZFS.